# Gltf- file, some materials doesn´t show in threejs editor

Tags: texturing, materials, gltf, three.js

Some of the materials and textures on my models doesn't show up in the threejs editor (https://threejs.org/editor/)

I export the files from blender (2.9) as gltf2.0-files, in blender i add textures from the addon "blenderkit" and it all looks good when i view them in blender.

As i open up the files in threejs editor some materials doesn't show at all and some materials views completely different than in blender (different scale and colors)

Do you guys know what i do wrong? i'll provide more info if you need!

best regards

Comment: The glTF export only supports a simple material made with more or less one Principled BSDF and image textures assigned to the sockets. For the options and node structure, consult the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html). If that is done and the model still doesn't display correctly, it's probably an issue with how you load and display the model with threejs.

Comment: Also note that fully-metallic materials require environment lighting (IBL) in three.js, and will be black without it. The three.js editor does not include this lighting by default, so you may want to ensure your material has metalness>0 before exporting.